# How to merge columns using custom QProxy in Qt for QTableView?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I'm using `QSqlTableModel` associated with some `QTableView`.

I have to display `firstName` and `secondName` in the one same column in my `QTableView`.
I also have to make search by these fields separately, and that's a problem: I can't just use `CONCAT(lastName, ' ', secondName)` in my SQL query, I have to keep `firstName` and `secondName` separately in some data structure

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
        db.setHostName("...")
        db.setDatabaseName("...")
        db.setUserName("...")
        db.setPassword("...")
        db.open()

        model.setQuery(u"""SELECT
                         CONCAT(c.firstName, ' ', c.lastName, ' ', c.patrName),
                         CONCAT(c.birthDate, ' / ', TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, c.birthDate, NOW())),
                         IF(c.sex = 1, 'M', 'F'),
                         CONCAT(p.serial, '-', p.number),
                         CONCAT(d.serial, '-', d.number)                         
                       FROM client AS c
                         JOIN clientpolicy AS p ON c.id = p.client_id
                         JOIN clientdocument AS d ON c.id = d.client_id""", db)

        self.ui.patientsTableView.setModel(model)
```

Now, for example I want to sort the table by `secondName`

Comment: Can you provide some code? you can use struct as your data structure. or [QPair](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpair.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own data structure in your table model

```
typedef struct sUserFullName
{
   QString oFistName;
   QString oLastName;
}USER_FULLNAME;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(USER_FULLNAME);

class MyCusumeModel : public QSqlTableModel
{
     Q_OBJECT

private:

    QList<USER_FULLNAME> m_oAllUsersNames;

    const QString& GetFirstName(int row) const
    {
       return m_oAllUsersNames.at(row).oFistName;
    }
    const QString& GetLastName(int row) const
    {
       return m_oAllUsersNames.at(row).oLastName;
    }

  public:

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

};
```

Handle column data in the cpp:

```
QVariant MyCusumeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
   // Valid index ?
   if (!index.isValid())
       return QVariant();

   // Validate size overflow.
   if (index.row() >= m_oAllUsersNames.size()) {
       return QVariant();
   }

   // Handle column data 
   switch (index.column()) {

   case 0: // Combine first + last Name
     if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
       return QString("%1, %2").arg(GetFirstName(index.row())).arg(GetLastName(index.row()));
     if (role == Qt::UserRole) 
       return m_oAllUsersNames(index.row()); // store data
     break;

  default:
     break;
 }
 return QVariant();

}
```

For sorting override [lessThan](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan) in the [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html)

example sorting by last name:

```
bool MyCustomeSortModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &oLeft, const QModelIndex &oRight) const
{
    USER_FULLNAME sLeftData = sourceModel()->data(oLeft, Qt::UserRole).value<USER_FULLNAME>();
    USER_FULLNAME sRightData = sourceModel()->data(oRight,Qt::UserRole).value<USER_FULLNAME>();   

    switch (oLeft.column()) {

    case 0:  // Sort by last name
        return sLeftData.oLastName < sRightData.oLastName;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    // Sort any other supported type
    return sourceModel()->data(oLeft, Qt::DisplayRole) < sourceModel()->data(oRight, Qt::DisplayRole);
}
```

Comment: I have a `QSqlTableModel`, so I want to make a proxy for it.

Comment: Can I get `QModelIndex` from a proxy's `data` method, knowing the original model's column and row?

Comment: Right, `class MyCusumeModel : public QSqlTableModel` and override the `data` function to handle table data